# Weird notifications popping up on desktop. Maybe a virus?

Tags: notification, malware

Some weird notifications are popping up on my Ubuntu that I use just for college.
For example:

Facebook
1 new private message

Now... I haven't used facebook for 4 years and I really don't know why I'd get this notification on my desktop. I'm afraid I've got some kind of "virus". How can I know what's that? And what should I do to get rid of it?

Ps: I didn't even imagined I'd be using Linux at the time I stopped using Facebook. Never logged in via Online Accounts.

[As you can see on this print, it's just a notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dybj4.png)

Comment: Check "Online Settings" "Online Accounts" Can't remember which and remove FaceBook.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't specify that I never logged in Facebook via Online Accounts.

Comment: Sounds like a browser problem. Does it ever appear if you don't have your web browser open? Does it appear if disable all of your extensions? Did you install any new extensions recently? Have a look at: [How can I identify malware containing Chrome extensions in Linux?](//superuser.com/q/724009)

Comment: It has not appeared when my browser isn't opened yet. I activated Firefox's safe mode ( disables all add-ons ), but it still appeared.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Today I was able to click on the pop-up window and it led me to a webpage "ttp://157.230.150.84/?number=+1-(888)-441-0565", which my router blocked access. The small popup window does not appear again after that so far.

Comment: It was firefox process that was showing the pop-up window in my machine. I uninstalled firefox and installed it again. So far it has not shown up again.

Comment: It's an "Allow Website Notifications". Here are the removal instructions: https://www.pcrisk.com/removal-guides/12625-allow-website-notifications-pop-up-scam#remove-notifications

Comment: Can confirm that this^^^ comment solved my problem.